# Java Calendar adds a random number of milliseconds?

Tags: java, datetime, java.util.calendar

Hi I have something weird happening. I am simply taking a calendar object, converting it to its individual parts, and putting it back into a calendar (with or without any changes. In this case I make no changes). I mean, this should be cut and paste. I've also tried to create a calendar with calendar = Calendar.getInstance() and set everything manually. calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mStartYear); so on. Still gives wrong Calendar objects. I've tried also setting Milliseconds, always seem to have some garbage milliseconds..  But the time one way or another just is completely off. Maybe someone sees the stupid oversight, but I'm stumped.

Also this is an android application, but shouldn't matter for a basic Java library object.

Note Weekview is a datawrapper for one of the libraries I'm using. It has a start and an end calendar.

Here is what the debugger lists as in memory..

```
mEndDay = 19
mEndHour = 9

mEndMinute = 30
mEndMonth = 8
mEndYear = 2015
mSeekAmount = 0
mStartDay = 18
mStartHour = 23
mStartMinute = 0
mStartMonth = 8
mStartYear = 2015


            Calendar calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarStart.set(mStartYear,mStartMonth,mStartDay,mStartHour,mStartMinute);

            Calendar calendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarEnd.set(mEndYear,mEndMonth,mEndDay,mEndHour,mEndMinute);
```

I end up with

```
Start 1442363359161
End 1442363359161

calendarStart = {GregorianCalendar@20968} "java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=America/Denver,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=38,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=258,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=6,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=0,SECOND=19,MILLISECOND=161,ZONE_OFFSET=-25200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]"
calendarEnd = {GregorianCalendar@20969} "java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=America/Denver,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=38,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=19,DAY_OF_YEAR=258,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=6,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=30,SECOND=19,MILLISECOND=161,ZONE_OFFSET=-25200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]"
```

EXPECT

```
Start 1442638800000
End 1442676600000

mEndTime = {GregorianCalendar@20990} "java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1442676600000,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=America/Denver,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=38,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=19,DAY_OF_YEAR=262,DAY_OF_WEEK=7,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=30,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-25200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]"
mName = {String@20991} "sleep"
mStartTime = {GregorianCalendar@20992} "java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1442638800000,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=America/Denver,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=38,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=261,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-25200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]"
```

Here is where I set it up initially..

```
   WeekViewEvent weekViewEvent = dateWrapperParam.getWeekViewEvent();
    Calendar endCalendar = weekViewEvent.getEndTime();
    Calendar startCalendar = weekViewEvent.getStartTime();

    Date endDate = endCalendar.getTime();
    Date startDate = startCalendar.getTime();

    mStartHour = startCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mStartMinute = startCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    mStartDay = startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mStartMonth = startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mStartYear = startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    mEndHour = endCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mEndMinute = endCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    mEndDay = endCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mEndMonth = endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mEndYear = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: No it doesn't, you never reset the milliseconds when you call `set`.  When you call `getInstance`, the `Calendar` is initialised to the CURRENT time in MILLISECONDS, unless you modify the value, it is never changed.  If you have a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-int-int-int-), it says *"Sets the values for the fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR_OF_DAY, MINUTE, and SECOND. **Previous values of other fields are retained**. If this is not desired, call clear() first."* (emphasis added by me)

Comment: Read it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html then you will came to the conclusion that: "Calendar is a specific instant in time" which means it is not random it is that current instant in time.

Comment: So, instead, call `Calendar#clear` FIRST before you call `Calendar#set`.  This is actually a known feature of `Calendar`

Comment: You are missing seconds and milliseconds in `Calendar` initialization, since the difference.

Comment: @maxZoom I actually did try the one with millisecond initialization and set it to 0. As well as setting it post facto. But I will try it again.

Comment: @maxzoom The clear fixed the issue. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @jorge Campos Sigh yeah I didn't think of that. That was the root of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments under your question , there is only difference in seconds and milliseconds between `startCalendar` and `calendarStart` time, because that values were not reset.

See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/I5HAgx)

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of [`Calendar.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), it is said :

> Sets the values for the fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. Previous values of other fields are retained. If this is not desired, call [clear()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28%29) first.

The reason is that not all fields are set with this method, in you case, you don't have `MILLISECOND` set. So it keep the value when the instance was created.

The call of [`Calendar.clear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28%29) will

> Sets all the calendar field values and the time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch) of this Calendar undefined.

A quick example :

```
    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    c.clear();
    c.set(2019, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 03, 16, 15, 03);

    System.out.println(c.getTime());
    System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

> Sun Nov 03 16:15:03 CET 2019
>   1572794103000

Milliseconds being undefined will give 0

Answer (score 0):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

I suggest that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. For example:

```
    ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ZonedDateTime end = start;
    
    System.out.println("Start: " + start);
    System.out.println("End:   " + end);
```

Output when I ran the code in my time zone just now:

> ```
> Start: 2020-06-24T19:24:04.811+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
> End:   2020-06-24T19:24:04.811+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
> ```

A `ZonedDateTime` is a date and time of day in some time zone. It’s the closest we come to a modern equivalent of `GregorianCalendar` (the subclass of `Calendar` that your code gave you). Which modern class to use varies with more precise requirements, so sometimes you will prefer to use for example `LocalDate`, `OffsetDateTime` or even `LocalTime`.

To truncate the values to whole minutes (setting seconds and fraction of second to 0):

```
    ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

> ```
> Start: 2020-06-24T19:24+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
> ```

`ZonedDateTime` and the other classes of java.time offer plenty of ways to modify the values obtained. For example:

```
    ZonedDateTime end = start.plusDays(2).withHour(13);
```

> ```
> End:   2020-06-26T13:24+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
> ```

If you want to create the end time manually using only selected fields from the start time:

```
    ZonedDateTime end = ZonedDateTime.of(
            2021, start.getMonthValue(), start.getDayOfMonth(),
            start.getHour(), 30, 0, 0, start.getZone());
```

> ```
> End:   2021-06-24T19:30+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
> ```

### What went wrong in your code?

Part of the answer is already in the other answers: The `set` methods of `Calendar` set only the fields they promise to set and leave other fields unchanged where possible. While this is probably expected from the `set​(int field, int value)` method, it often surprises with the `set​(int year, int month, int date)` method and even more with `set​(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute)` and `set​(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)`. In general while well intended the `Calendar` class and its subclasses are poorly and confusingly designed and cumbersome to work with. This is the main reason why I recommend java.time above.

The other part of the answer is that `Calendar` calculates its fields leniently. So when you look at the `Calendar` object in your debugger after calling `set`, it will contain a lot of garbage values. Calling `getTime()` forces the `Calendar` to compute its fields, so after that call the way it looks in the debugger should make more sense. Again it’s confusing behaviour, and it can also sometimes be observed without using the debugger.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the Calendar object, it is getting the current time including the current second and millisecond. The code provided sets the hour and minute, but it does not set the second and millisecond, leaving it as it was when the Calendar object was initialized.
In order to set the second and nanosecond to zero, use:

```
StartCalendar.set(Year, Month, DayofMonth, Hour, Minute, 0,0);
```